# Counting elements of a list and sublists

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm trying to create a function to count all the elements in a list, including the elements of its sublists. initially, to get started, i came up with a basic function `myList`:

```
(define myLength 
  (lambda (L)
    (cond
      ((null? L) 0)
      (else (+ 1 (myLength (cdr L)))))))
```

However, it doesn't help me account for function calls like:

```
(numAtoms '())              "...should be 0"
(numAtoms '(()))            "...should be 0"
(numAtoms '(1 1))           "...should be 2"
(numAtoms '(1 (1 1) 1))     "...should be 4"
(numAtoms '(1 (1 (1 1)) 1)) "...should be 5"
```

I'm trying to use basic functions like `length`, `null?`, and `list?`.

Comment: You mixing two cases together. You want to do something different if the car of L is a list.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why teachers bother to give homework anymore... Hope they don't try to grade effort or achievement based on it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the trick here is to imagine how you can transform your input into the *code* that you'd want to use to compute the sum.  Let's write each of your inputs in the fully expanded form, in terms of `cons` and `'()` and whatever other atoms appear in your data:

```
'()               == '()
'(())             == (cons '() '())
'(1 1)            == (cons 1 (cons 1 '()))
'(1 (1 1) 1)      == (cons 1 (cons 1 (cons 1 '())) (cons 1 '()))
'(1 (1 (1 1)) 1)  == ...
```

Now, look what would happen if you replaced each occurrence of `cons` with `+`, and each occurrence of `'()` with `0`, and each occurrence of something that's not `'()` with `1`.  You'd have:

```
'()                                         => 0                           == 0
(cons '() '())                              => (+ 0 0)                     == 0
(cons 1 (cons 1 '()))                       => (+ 1 (+ 1 0))               == 2
(cons 1 (cons 1 (cons 1 '())) (cons 1 '())) => (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 0)) (+ 1 0)) == 4
...                                         => ...                         == ...
```

Notice that those *sums* are exactly the values that you want!  Based on this, it seems like you might not want to treat your input as a *list* so much as  a *tree* built from cons cells.  In general, you can map over a tree by specifying a function to apply to the recursive results of processing a pair, and a function to process the atoms of the tree:

```
(define (treeduce pair-fn atom-fn tree)
  (if (pair? tree)
      (pair-fn (treeduce pair-fn atom-fn (car tree))
               (treeduce pair-fn atom-fn (cdr tree)))
      (atom-fn tree)))
```

You could then implement that mapping of `cons` to `+` and everything else to `1` if it's a list and `0` if it's not by:

```
(define (non-null-atoms tree)
  (treeduce +
            (lambda (atom) 
              (if (not (null? atom))
                  1
                  0))
            tree))
```

This yields the kinds of results you'd expect:

```
(non-null-atoms '())              ;=> 0
(non-null-atoms '(()))            ;=> 0
(non-null-atoms '(1 1))           ;=> 2
(non-null-atoms '(1 (1 1) 1))     ;=> 4
(non-null-atoms '(1 (1 (1 1)) 1)) ;=> 5
```

Comment: im sorry but im kinda a beginner in racket. what does predicate, pair? and treeduce do?

Comment: @user2989977 I (hope that I) have clarified and simplified the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive template you can use:

```
(define (num-atoms lst)
  (cond ((pair? lst) (+ (num-atoms <??>) 
                        (num-atoms <??>)))
        ((null? lst) <??>) ; not an atom
        (else <??>)))      ; an atom
```

This next example uses a helper that has the accumulated value (num) as an argument.

```
(define (num-atoms lst)
  ;; locally defined helper
  (define (helper num lst)
    (cond ((pair? lst) (helper (helper <??> <??>) <??>)) ; recurse with the sum of elements from car
          ((null? lst) <??>)          ; return accumulated value
          (else (helper <??> <??>)))) ; recurse with add1 to num

  ;; procedure starts here
  (helper 0 lst))
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Make `my-length` work for any argument type, list or 'atom'; then the recursive algorithm becomes almost trivial:

```
(define (my-length l)
  (cond ((null? l) 0)
        ((list? l) (+ (my-length (car l)) (my-length (cdr l))))
        (else 1)))  ; atom

> (my-length '(1 (1 (1 1)) 1)))
5
```