# How can i count all natural elements in list (using mzscheme)

Tags: list, count, scheme

function name = mycount

here is output example:

```
(mycount 20) -> error(must standard error)
(mycount `()) -> 0
(mycount `(1 2 3)) - > 6
(mycount `((1 2) ((3)) (4 (5)))) -> 15
```

Comment: `(apply + (flatten lst))`

Comment: Well, I'm just going to remove my answer.

Comment: I always forget about the powerful BIF's of FP and my answer is too verbose, I presume :)

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer I'm pretty sure the OP is not allowed to use `flatten`. And, btw, it doesn't work for the first use-case.

Comment: **count** is not the same as **sum**. Thus is you want to count natural number in `(1 2 3)` it's `3` not `6`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting elements of a list and sublists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060772/counting-elements-of-a-list-and-sublists)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We would like to see some effort on your part to solve your problem. And as Sylwester says, this has been asked before.

Answer (score -1):

```
function count-numbers takes a list:
    define a counter
    is it a number?
       ERROR
    is it a list?
        for each element of list:
            cond
                - is it a number? -> increase the counter
                - is it a list?   -> apply (count-numbers) to it and add the result to counter
                - do nothing
```

Something like that? We are not going to make your homework :)

Comment: Not idiomatic Scheme (i.e. not functional)

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Or is it the definition of the counter? (i.e., assignment in the function)

Comment: You mutate `counter`. A classical roll-your-own Scheme solution would be `(let loop ((lst lst)(count 0)) (if (null? lst) count (loop (cdr lst) (if (natural? (car lst)) (+ 1 count) count))))` that updates counter by recursion.