# how to write tree-map function using apply in scheme

Tags: tree, scheme, racket

after writing:

```
(define (tree-accumulate tree)
  (if (pair? tree)
      (apply + (car tree) (map tree-accumulate (cdr tree)))
(+ tree)))
```

ex:
(tree-accumulate '(1 1 1 (1 (1 (1 1 1) 1 1) 1 1 (1 1 1 (1 1 1)))))
==> 18

how does one write a tree-map function so that you can write:

```
(define (tree-accumulate tree)
        (tree-map + tree))
```

tried:

```
(define (tree-map f tree)
  (if (pair? tree)
      (apply + (car tree) (map (tree-map (cdr tree)) )
      (f tree)))
```

but the problem is how to put in the f param in: (map (tree-map (cdr tree))
for the apply to still work?

Comment: This isn't a map so much as a fold (as an answer mentions).  Have a look [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20060982/1281433) to [Counting elements of a list and sublists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060772/counting-elements-of-a-list-and-sublists) which includes a **treeduce** (tree-reduce) function that does what you're looking for, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been noted, this isn't a map but a fold.

Nevertheless, you only need to "wrap" the recursive application in another function so you can pass `f` on:

```
(define (tree-fold f tree)
  (if (pair? tree)
      (apply f (car tree) (map (lambda (t) (tree-fold f t)) (cdr tree)))
      (f tree)))
```

An actual map could look like this:

```
(define (tree-map f tree)
  (if (pair? tree)
      (cons (f (car tree)) (map (lambda (t) (tree-map f t)) (cdr tree)))
      (f tree)))
```

Comment: followup:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530711/tree-fold-defintion-that-works-both-with-and-append

Answer (score 1):

Well, such a function wouldn't be called a `map`. It's actually more like a `fold`, similar to [`foldr`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) or [`foldl`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29). So anyway, here's one possible definition of `tree-accumulate` using a `tree-foldl` function:

```
(define (tree-accumulate tree)
  (tree-foldl + 0 tree))
```

The `0` as the second argument is the base case, for when there are no leaves in the tree. The `tree-foldl` function can be defined like this:

```
;; (Treeof A) is one of:
;;  - A
;;  - (Listof (Treeof A))
;; Where the A type can't include lists.

;; tree-foldl : [A B -> B] B (Treeof A) -> B
;; Where the A type can't include lists.
(define (tree-foldl f base tree)
  (cond [(not (list? tree))
         (f tree base)]
        [else
         (tree-foldl/list f base tree)]))

;; tree-foldl/list : [A B -> B] B (Listof (Treeof A)) -> B
;; Where the A type can't include lists.
(define (tree-foldl/list f base tree)
  (cond [(empty? tree)
         base]
        [else
         (tree-foldl/list f
                          (tree-foldl f base (first tree))
                          (rest tree))]))
```

Using `tree-accumulate` with this definition,

```
> (tree-accumulate '(1 1 1 (1 (1 (1 1 1) 1 1) 1 1 (1 1 1 (1 1 1)))))
18
```