# tree-fold defintion that works both with + and append

Tags: tree, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, fold

```
(define (tree-fold f tree)
  (if (pair? tree)
      (apply f (car tree) (map (lambda (t) (tree-fold f t)) (cdr tree)))
      (f tree)))
```

works for example with: `(tree-fold + '(1 (2 2)(2 2))` -> 9

However if I want to use `(tree-fold append '(1 (2 2)(2 2)))`,
I have to modify the `tree-fold` with `list` around `(car tree)`,
which breaks it for `+`.
Is there some mechanism that can be used in the `tree-fold` definition that would make it work with both `+` and `append`?

Comment: First identify the 'break', and the violated expectations that cause it.

Comment: Think about the types of each function involved. The `+` function has the type `number? number? -> number?`. The `append` function has the type `list? list? -> list?`. At first blush, these both seem like reasonable functions to provide to `tree-fold`, but there is a hidden bias here. The `tree-fold` function always invokes `f` with an element of the tree *and* some other result of `f`. Therefore, for a tree of numbers, `tree-fold` actually has the type `(number? a -> a) list? -> a`. The `append` function is not compatible with the first argument of this type, but another function is: `cons`.

Comment: What kind of way to you want the fold to associate? There are a few different ways to do a tree traversal and it's reverse.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, adding one parameter to initialise the result:

```
(define (tree-fold f n sxp)
  (let loop ((sxp sxp) (res n))
    (cond
      ((null? sxp) res)
      ((pair? sxp) (loop (car sxp) (loop (cdr sxp) res)))
      (else        (f sxp res)))))
```

Testing:

```
> (tree-fold + 0 '(1 (2 2)(2 2)))
9
> (tree-fold cons '() '(1 (2 3)(4 5)))
'(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Comment: could you please make the variables more readable? as in self commenting code :)

Comment: You can just substitute `tree` for `sxp`. `res` is supposed to mean "result" and `f` is from your code ;-)